# Why is the Email Form (ASP.net ) only sending internal email, but not external

Tags: asp.net, forms, email

Though the issue does not appear to be code-related, I thought I'd try and see if I could get some direction as to what would cause my online form to all of a sudden to stop delivering emails when an external address is use. E.g The form works well when using the company email address: fullname@**mycompany**.com ...however if I use an address such as fullname@gmail.com, the email fails. The forms been working fine, so am assuming some sort of permissions on the server has changed. The form is written in ASP.net and running on Windows Server 2012 
...My Admin is currently unavailable and I was wondering where can I start as far as diagnosing the issue. Thanks in advance for any suggestions rendered.

Comment: This question is very difficult to answer without code, especially since it's more likely to be a hardware/server/firewall problem...

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not clear, I don't understand what you mean by

> using the company email address.

May be you mean using company email as From for message?
If like that your SMTP server  accept only message from specific From.

Comment: I tried to give an answer based on my own experience having had to face a similar issue...but question is too poor to correctly identify the problem.